pipe with sum() returns a weird answer
When I used the pipe, I got a strange answer. Why?
sum( x * y ) returned a right answer.
But x * y |> sum() returned a strange answer.
I want to know why it happened.
And is it possible for sum() to return multiple numbers?
x <- c(1:2)
y <- c(3:4)

sum( x * y )    # right return 11
x * y |> sum()  # strange return 7 14 (two numbers!)


Try (x * y) |> sum() - lookup operator precedence.

Oh, yes! Thanks.

I think you should use
> x <- c(1:2)

> y <- c(3:4)

> (x * y) |> sum()
[1] 11

otherwise, x*y|>sum() is interpreted as x*(sum(y)), which results c(7, 14)


Thanks for the suggestion from SamR in the comment
> substitute(x * y |> sum())
x * sum(y)

> substitute((x * y) |> sum())
sum((x * y))


@SamR thank you for your suggestion, I added it in my answer, cheers!

Now I forget -- does magrittr::%>% follow the same precedence?

@CarlWitthoft yes, the same
